# I want to upload files to Blob Storage NOT AS STREAMS (Buffer, base64) BUT AS original file (jpg , png jpeg)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

I am unable to find a way to upload a file not as a stream (buffer, base64) but as a file(png,jgeg,jpg) to Azure Storage Blob.

MY Stream Code is

```
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential, defaultAzureCredentials
);

createBlob = (blobName,blob)=>{
    try{
      async function main() {
          const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('blue');
          const content = base64_encode(blob.buffer);
          const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
          const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content, content.length);
          console.log(`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
          return uploadBlobResponse.requestId;
        }

        main();
  }
  catch(err){
      res.send(err)
  }
}

function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    //var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return file.toString('base64');
}
```

Comment: You basically upload the buffer (which is binary data) and name the blob appropriately. I'm not understanding what's the issue in that. Can you please explain?

Comment: The question lacks clarity - as I read it you are asking how to upload a file as a file.

Comment: @GauravMantri This is the basic upload code from the azure documentation. I don't know why you didn't understand

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you were using [`@azure/storage-blob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) and your code inspired from [`Create a blob by uploading data to`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob#create-a-blob-by-uploading-data-to).

There is a function [`uploadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadfile-string--blockblobparalleluploadoptions-) of `BlockBlobClient` that can help to directly upload a local file to Azure Blob Storage, as the figure below.

[image]

Here is my sample code.

```
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

// Enter your storage account name and shared key
const account = "<your account name>";
const accountKey = "<your account key>";

// Use StorageSharedKeyCredential with storage account and account key
// StorageSharedKeyCredential is only avaiable in Node.js runtime, not in browsers
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential
);

var containerName = '<your container name>';
var blobName = '<your blob name>';

const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

var filePath = '<your local file path>';
blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath);
```

Comment: you have to first upload it on the system to get file path. That i do not want. It has to go directly to the blob

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the content type in the options

```js
  await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream, bufferSize, maxConcurrency, {
    blobHTTPHeaders: {
      blobContentType: "image/jpeg"
    }
  })
```

Comment: you have to pass the stream instead of buffer in the first parameter